# The image wont open on html?

Tags: html

I am trying to add these Images to html but they it will not open, I have tried changing the name along with other methods.

```
<img src="/Pictures/cycling_plus.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:128px;height:128px;">


<img src="Pictures/robotjuice.jpg" alt=""Robot Header" id="headerIMG" />
```

Comment: what have you tried? do you have some code?

Comment: are the images actually there? You should see errors in your console if they are not

Comment: Try pulling up the image in just the browser window (to make sure it exists and can be viewed)

Comment: Are you trying on your desktop right? Make sure that the Pictures folder is in the same directory as the HTML. Lets say your HTML file is in the folder "website". On this folder, you have to put your tho images in a Pictures folder. So your final project would be something like this: html: `website/index.html`, image 1: `website/Pictures/cycling_plus.jpg`, image 2: `website/Pictures/robotjuice.jpg`.

Comment: Be careful when using a leading slash (`/`) in file paths. A leading slash means it is an absolute path, which will cause the link or image to break in a lot of situations.

Answer (score 1):

May be alt=""Robot Header" is breaking your code because you have an extra ".
Also the first image is missing the final "/" but that shouldn't affect.

Comment: I would like to add an explanation here why the extra `/` won't affect. In HTML5 the Self-closing tags are valid in both ways: `<tagname />` and `<tagname>`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes here:

1. `/Pictures/imageName.jpg` isn't equal to `Pictures/imageName.jpg`
2. `alt=""Robot Header"` should be `alt="Robot Header"`.
   *However, this won't affect displaying the image by any means!*
3. Check your Browser Console. Press `F12` from your keyboard on your browser, then choose `Console` from the menu.
   You will see an error like this:
   `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

[image: Developer Tools Console]

After making sure that you've fixed the 3 mistakes above, your images would be displayed without any issues.

*If you couldn't fix it, please take a screenshot of your Website Files, and your HTML Code as well*